# Haskell List comprehension printing only even numbers

Tags: list, haskell

```
 let nums = [4,5,2,6,2,6,44,1213]
```

I have to use list comprehension to filter the list defined by nums, so that it does not contain any even number or any numbers larger than 50

I dont know why I cannot figure this out!

```
 [x | x <- [nums], x == even, x <= 50]
```

Answer (score 5):

To filter the even numbers no greater than 50:

```
[x | x <- nums, even x, x <= 50]
```

To filter the odd numbers no greater than 50:

```
[x | x <- nums, not $ even x, x <= 50]
```

Comment: There is `odd` instead of `not . even`?

Answer (score 4):

Try `[x | x <- nums, even x, x <= 50]`. `nums` is already a list, when you put the extra square brackets around it it means that `x` will iterate over the elements in the list `[nums]`, not the list `nums`.  You also shouldn't be comparing `x` to `even`.  `even` is a function, not a value, it has type `even :: Int -> Bool`, so use it as `even x`.  That would be like saying `x == (<= 50)`, which wouldn't make much sense.